Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\binom{2n-1-i}{n-1}}{2^i\cdot \binom{2n}{n}}=\frac23$
I need to study the following summation formula involving binomial coefficients: $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\binom{2n-1-i}{n-1}}{2^i\cdot \binom{2n}{n}}.$
Interestingly, through numerical experiments, I found that this sequence is monotonically decreasing and converges to $\frac{2}{3}$. I'm eager to prove this result, but I have no idea where to start.

According to Mathematica, the given sum is equal to a hypergeometric function: $$a_n=\frac12 {_2}F_1(1,-n;1-2n,1/2)$$ (Note that a negative integer as one of the upper parameters of a hypergeometric function results in a finite sum, just as it does here.) Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ is however not so simple: the above hypergeometric function diverges when $n$ is a half-integer, so if the limit exists it's only as a sequence and not for $n$ as a real number.

Since $$\sum_{p=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^p\frac{\binom{n-1+p-i}{p-i}}{2^i}\right)z^p=\frac2{(2-z)(1-z)^n}=:f(z)$$ is a rational function and you want $[z^n]:f(z)$, you could probably use some “analytic combinatorics” tool.

Where does the sum come from?

Let $a(n,k)$ denote the $k^\text{th}$ term of the $n^\text{th}$ sum, so $a(n,k)=\binom{2n-1-k}{n-1}/\big(\binom{2n}n2^k\big)$ and $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a(n,k)$. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a(n,k)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-1-k)!}\cdot 2^k}
\\&=(1/2)^{2k+1}\cdot  \frac{\lim_{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}}{\lim_n \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-1-k)!\cdot (2n)^{k+1}}}
\\&=(1/2)^{2k+1}.
\end{align}\tag1
$$
Furthermore, $$a(n,k)\le 2^{-k}.\tag2$$ Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, together with the dominated convergence theorem, you get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n a(n,k)\stackrel{\text{DCT}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} a(n,k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1/2)^{2k+1}=\frac{1/2}{1-1/4}=2/3. 
$$

Thanks for your proof. But I am still interested in the monotonicity of $a_n$. Is this easy to prove?

As @Semiclassical pointed out, the result is $\frac12 {_2}F_1(1,-n;1-2n,1/2)$. For integer $n$, you can evaluate this using Gauss' continued fraction, see here .
You get
$$
\frac12 \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n/2}{1-2n+\frac{(n-1)/2}{2-2n + \frac{\cdots}{\cdots}}}}
$$
which in the limit of $n\to \infty$ is
$$
\frac12 \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n/2}{-2n + \cal O (1)} } = \frac12 \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}} = \frac23
$$
as you found numerically.

Nicely done. In principle one presumably could get finer approximations by going deeper into the continued fraction, e.g., one should have asymptotic behavior $2/3-2/(27n)$ for large $n$. But that might be a bit tedious, since It seems to require going to where the last denominator is $3-2n$.)
